# selenium python doesnt login into social media

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

So im pretty new to selenium and im following the docs to make some bots,
but when i try to login into social media networks (twitter/instagram) it doesnt send the strokes.

Code:

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
elem.send_keys('Laptops' + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(4)
browser.quit()
```

i've tried it by using- browser.get_element_by_name/class/xpath but nothing seemed to work.
Error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ig.py", line 50, in <module>
    login(driver)
  File "ig.py", line 15, in login
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
  File "/home/lario/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/lario/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 843, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/lario/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/lario/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div/input[@name='username']
```

os=ubuntu17
driver=firefox/geckodriver
python3.6
selenium3.6

I know this code shouldnt work bc you need a password and a username, but it doesnt even execute the send_keys code because of the error on the line above tHAT

Comment: use some implicit wait . Try this and let me know `browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/');
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('Laptops')`

Comment: It is showing error here `//div/input[@name='username']`. where you have mentioned this i m not seeing this ?

Comment: Infect it working fine in chrome

Comment: the code isnt working, is there any solution to fix this without changing my browser to chrome/?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems with Firefox driver on linux too.
I copied your code and only changed the driver to Chrome and it worked.
You can get the Chrome driver here:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wait-for presence condition. It may however require a EC.element_to_be_clickable, if the element is disabled until some check is performed.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
...

usernamefield = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)\
    .until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
usernamefield.send_keys("Laptops")
passwordfield = WebDriverWait(...
```